# Русские символы не отображаются.

Tags: php, utf-8, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемый спецы. Проблема у меня такого плана:
есть база данных, в ней:

> название текста
>
> краткое содержание
>
> сам текст

Все это в базе хранится в кодировке `utf8_general_ci`.
В папке сайта лежит файл `.htaccess`, в котором прописал
`AddDefaultCharset utf8`.

Проблема следующая: если я вписываю русские символы прямо в `php` страницу - никаких проблем нет, а вот если вывожу данные из БД, то происходит сбивка кодировки и текст отображается непонятными. Причем цифры и англ. буквы нормально, а русский текст именно не отображается.

Использую последний денвер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: а конкретно куда это прописать не подскажешь? Спасибо.

Comment: Сразу после коннекта к базе данных.

Comment: Спасибо, сэр. Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому-то пригодиться, как мне например, то теперь так:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

где, `$conn` -  Идентификатор соединения;

т.е. `$conn = mysqli_connect(....);`